# SQL with one column - check if row exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I stuck on something stupid..
     I have the table that has only one column.
     I want to check if there is some value, which I get from the url (method $_GET)

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error());

 $row=htmlspecialchars($_GET['row']);

 $query = @mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE row=$row");


 if ($result = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 

 echo "There is that row";
 }


 else {
 echo "There is not that row";
 }
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: as result I get "There is not that row" even if it is there

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to check if the resultset contains any rows. You can do this with **[mysql_num_rows()](http://pt1.php.net/mysql_num_rows)**:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {
 echo "There is that row";
}
else {
 echo "There is not that row";
}
```

Also if your `$row` is a string, you should enclose it in single quotes.

#### Note:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory "you should be using PDO" comment.

You don't say what sort of field it is, maybe it is a text field so it needs to be in quotes.

```
$query = @mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE row='" . $row . "');
```

Also if you remove the @ you might get to see some sort of error

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE row='" . $row . "') or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix row and column. When querying SQL database you usually specify `clumnName="value"` after WHERE statement. You have valid syntax for a table with one column named "row".

There might be a problem in your query as you do not escape your arguments, so it will fail it $row actually has any quotes in it. This would be avoided with use of PDO instead of `mysql_` functions which are no longer maintained. Query your table like this instead:

```
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gvar WHERE gvarebi='{addslashes($row)}'");
```

To actually check if there are any results, it is better to use `mysql_num_rows` as it will return number of rows for specified query. So update your code with this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "row exists";
} else {
    echo "row does not exists";
}
```

Comment: result is the same, I get the message "row does not exists" =(

Comment: Here is the exact code:  $gvari=htmlspecialchars($_GET['gvari']);

$query = @mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM gvarebi WHERE gvari=''");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    echo "<br><br><br><br>row exists";
} else {
    echo "<br><br><br><br>row does not exists";
}

Comment: please provide information on what is $row ($gvari) set to. Also, what is the name of the column in the table, I am sure it is not "row"?

Comment: I have poor English, so please forgive me If I understand incorrectly.  The table is called "gvarebi", the column is called "gvari". Here you can see: http://tyche.ge/table.jpg

Comment: I have updated my answer (see ` $query = ...`). If that does not solve it, then you might have problems with UTF-8 encoding